# Fast and elegant one-way mapping of known integer values

Tags: c++

I have to map a set of known integers to another set of known integers, 1-to-1 relationship, all predefined and so on. So, suppose I have something like this (c++, simplified, but you'll get the idea):

```
struct s { int a; int b; };

s theMap[] = { {2, 5}, {79, 12958 } };
```

Now given an input integer, say 79, I'd need to find the corresponding result from theMap (obviously 12958). Any nice and fast method of doing this, instead of your run-of-the-mill for loop? Other data structure suggestions are also welcome, but the map should be easy to write in the source by hand.

The values in both sets are in the range of 0 to 2^16, and there are only about 130 pairs. What I also am after is a very simple way of statically initializing the data.

Comment: What else can you tell us about your sets of integer pairs, in particular about the first elements of the pairs ?  The best answer to your question depends on the nature of your data.

Comment: Edited a bit. Forgot to mention though that there is no clear sequence or pattern in the sets. You can think of them as a bunch of seemingly random numbers.

Comment: In response to your edit, the simplest way of statically initialising things is to do what you are doing now, use ygrek's binary search suggestion and Potatoswatter's idea of having the records in the required order (I'd want to write a test function I could run to check I'd got the last bit right).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a map

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::map <int, int> m;
   m[79] = 12958; 
   std::cout << m[79] << std::endl;
}
```

Using a map is the most general solution and  the most portable (the C++ standard does not yet support hash tables, but they are  a very common extension). It isn't necessariily the fastest though. Both the binary search and the hashmap solutions suggested by others may (but not will) out-perform it. This probably won't matter for most applications, however.

Comment: +1. Maps are implemented with balanced binary search trees, so the speed of a binary search and search in a map are the same (disregarding the small constants). Moreover, for about 130 pairs, that means that searching for a single element will take about 7/8 comparisons in the worst case. The same goes for hashmaps... how fast must the hash function be to be comparably faster than 8 comparisons/dereferences?

Comment: Just to complete the last requirement: for the static initialization part, consider using boost::assign.

Answer (score 8):

Sort the array by the key and do the binary search.

Comment: +1 This is a very good solution if things are added to the map once in one go, which it looks like is what the OP is doing.

Comment: @ Potatoswatter Too easy to get wrong - and it's the kind of error that is very hard to see.

Comment: @Neil: but it *is* very easy to check during unit testing, and saves a little run-time. Tradeoffs. Certainly don't test it by Mk I eyeball.

Comment: @dmckee Indeed - see my comment in the question re testing.

Answer (score 7):

If you need compile time mapping you could use the following template:

```
// template to specialize
template<int T> struct int2int {};    

// macro for simplifying declaration of specializations
#define I2I_DEF(x, v) template<> struct int2int<x> { static const int value = v; };

// definitions
I2I_DEF(2, 5) I2I_DEF(79, 12958) I2I_DEF(55, 100) // etc.

// use
#include <iostream>    
int main()
{
  std::cout << int2int<2>::value << " " << int2int<79>::value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the number of your source integers `i` is relatively high (so that a direct search becomes inefficient) but still manageable, you can relatively easily build a perfect hash function `hash(i)` for your input integers (using [Pearson hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing), for example) and then use the hashed value as the entry into the output table `map`

```
output = map[hash(i)];
```

Of course, if the range of the input values is relatively small, you can use the identity function in place of `hash` and just turn the whole thing into a straghforward remapping

```
output = map[i];
```

(although if that was the case you wouldn't probably even ask.)

Answer (score 2):

```
std::map<int, int> theMap;
theMap[2] = 5;
std::map<int, int>::const_iterator iter = theMap.find(2);
if (iter != theMap.end())
   iter->second; // found it
```

Insert pairs of ints, retrieve value by key, logarithmic complexity. If you have a really large data set and need faster retrieval use std::tr1::unordered_map or boost::unordered_map (in case your standard library doesn't have TR1 implementation).

Answer (score 2):

[std::map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) or [std::unordered_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/unordered/index.html) is probably the cleanest you'll get. Unfortunately C++ has no built-in associative arrays.

```
std::map<int,int> mymap; // the same with unordered map

// one way of inserting
mymap.insert ( std::make_pair(2,5) );
mymap.insert ( std::make_pair(79,12958) );

// another
mymap[2] = 5;
mymap[79] = 12958;
```

To check

```
std::map<int,int>::const_iterator iter = mymap.find(2);
if ( iter != mymap.end() )
{
   // found
   int value = iter->second;
}
```

`unordered_map` has the advantage of `O(1)` amortized lookup time as opposed to `O(log n)` of `map`.

Comment: A map is an associative array, or at least behaves like one.

Comment: In most implementations, it is a binary tree.

Comment: @Niel: it's not built-in is it?

Comment: @Travis That's the implementation - there is no such data structure as an "associative array" - you have to implement them using trees, hashes or whatever.

Comment: @Kornel What's not built in? An associative array is one where you can use any type (but typically a string) to access a value. That's what a map does. Using a map is just like using an AA in a language that explicitly says it has  them, like awk.

Comment: @Niel: let me rephrase -- an associative array is not a built-in type of C++, contrary to an array for example.

Answer (score 2):

As a supplementary, if you need a binary search implementation, don't overlook the C++ Standard Library. The following does one on an array of your structure type using the equal_range algorithm (apologies for the somewhat hacky quality of the code)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct S {
    int k, v;
};

bool operator <( const S & a, const S & b ) {
    return a.k < b.k;
};

// must be sorted in key order
S values[] = {{42,123},{666,27}};

int main() {

    S t;
    cin >> t.k;

    S * valend = &values[0] + sizeof(values) / sizeof(S);
    pair <S*,S*> pos = equal_range( &values[0], valend , t);

    if ( pos.first != pos.second ) {
        cout << pos.first->v << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "no" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not a hashed map? It will give you more or less constant retrieval times for any key.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea, it's a map. Use [std::map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html).

Answer (score 1):

Jump table. A switch will likely set this up if you are able to use that, otherwise you may need some assembly but that's probably the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boost::assign.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef std::map< int, int > int2int_t;
    typedef int2int_t::const_iterator int2int_cit;

    const int2int_t theMap
        = boost::assign::map_list_of
            ( 2, 5 )
            ( 79, 12958 )
            ;

    int2int_cit it = theMap.find( 2 );
    if ( it != theMap.end() )
    {
        const int result = it->second;
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% certain `theMap` won't grow to over 1,000 entries (profile!), it's probably faster to do a binary search.

If the the value of `a` has a reasonable bound (e.g. below 1,000), you can just make a simple array with `a` as the index for guaranteed O(1) complexity. If you're using gcc you can use this syntax (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits):

```
int theMap[256] = { [2] = 5, [79] = 12958 };
```

(This is not supported by g++, unfortunately)

In any other cases, use `std::unordered_map` as shown in the other answers.

Comment: I'm with MSVC here, so I guess it's not designated initializers for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudocode is almost valid C++0x code — but C++0x requires less!

```
map<int, int> theMap = { {2, 5}, {79, 12958 } };
assert ( theMap[ 2 ] == 5 );
```

In "normal" C++, you have to initialize the map like this, still quite elegant:

```
pair< int, int > map_array[2] = { make_pair(2, 5), make_pair(79, 12958) };
map< int, int > theMap( &map_array[0], &map_array[2] ); // sorts the array
assert ( theMap[ 2 ] == 5 );
```

This is fast to write and fast to run!

<s>**Edit:** Just don't make the map a global variable. (Although that is safe in C++0x.) If you do, it will only be initialized properly if the compiler chooses to initialize it after map_array, which is VERY not guaranteed. If you want to to be a global, initialize it with `theMap.assign( &map_array[0], &map_array[2] );`.</s>

Comment: If it's not global, where else can you place? (static variables in a class is also kind-of global.)

Comment: @KennyTM: If you make it global, call `assign` — that's all.

Comment: global variables in one file are guaranteed to be initialized in the order of appearance, aren't they?

Comment: @ygrek: I think you're right, actually. I can't find that guarantee anywhere, though, closest is that §3.6.2/3 says putting things in *opposite* order may be broken.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a technique known as "xmacros" which is a nice way to do exactly what you are talking about as well.  However, it is easy to abuse the technique so I always recommend using it with care.  Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#X-Macros

The basic gist is, you have a file where you list out your mappings say foo.txt which looks like this:
MAP(2,5)
MAP(79,12958)
...

Then you define a macro MAP(A,B) that takes those two arguments and does your initialization for you.  Then #include the file (foo.txt).  You can even do it in multiple passes if you like by redefining the macro between each #include of the file.  Then to add more mappings you simply add them to foo.txt and recompile.  It is very powerful and can be used for many different things.

Comment: It may not have been clear above but the xmacros are more of a way to do easy initialization of whatever data struct or technique you go with.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a map for whatever reason, (for example, you just want to use the array you set up at compile time), you can also use a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) in combination with `<algorithm>`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct s { int a; int b; };

s theMap[] = { {2, 5}, {79, 12958 } };

struct match_key : public unary_function<s, bool>
{
    match_key(int key) : key_(key) {};
    bool operator()(const s& rhs) const
    {
        return rhs.a == key_;
    }
private:
    int key_;
};

int main()
{
    size_t mapSize = sizeof(theMap)/sizeof(theMap[0]);
    s* it = find_if(&theMap[0], &theMap[mapSize], match_key(79));
    cout << it->b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: find_if does a sequential search - the user specifically asked about "fast". See my second answer for a binary search version.